# "five years since I have been playing tennis"

Tags: tenses

Can anyone tell me whether this sentence is grammatically correct or not?

- *It's been 5 years since I have been playing tennis now.*

Whats wrong in this sentence?

Comment: It's correct, except it should be "It's" in the beginning, not "Its"

Comment: If you mean that it's been 5 years since you have played tennis (i.e, you haven't played in the last 5 years), then it shouldn't be progressive: _It's been 5 years now since I have played tennis._ However, if you mean that you have been playing tennis for the last 5 years (i.e, you started 5 years ago, instead of stopping -- the opposite meaning), then there should be no _since_: _It's been 5 years now (that) I've been playing tennis._

Comment: @John Lawler this is right, I didn't look properly at the 'since'. A modification if you want to include 'since': "It's been 5 years since I started playing tennis"

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep durations separate from punctual events, and beginnings separate from endings. That's essentially what the little details keep straight; sort of like courtesy lights at one's feet to show you the way to go -- they don't illuminate anything, but they do the job. That's what grammar's for; the illumination is in the meaningful words.

Comment: If I heard this, I would guess that the native language of the speaker is not English.  But I would understand the meaning, so there is no harm in it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds unnecessarily wordy for the idea it is trying to convey. Try "It's now five years since I (last) played tennis."

Comment: If that’s the meaning you’re going for (which is probably not what OP had in mind) and you’re trying to be less wordy, try: *”I haven’t played tennis in [over] 5 years.*”